# Hibernate Batch Insert. Would it ever use one insert instead of multiple inserts?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, batch-file

I've been looking around trying to determine some Hibernate behavior that I'm unsure about. In a scenario where Hibernate batching is properly set up, will it only ever use multiple insert statements when a batch is sent? Is it not possible to use a DB independent multi-insert statement?

I guess I'm trying to determine if I actually have the batching set up correctly. I see the multiple insert statements but then I also see the line "Executing batch size: 25."

There's a lot of code I could post but I'm trying to keep this general. So, my questions are:

1) What can you read in the logs to be certain that batching is being used?

2) Is it possible to make Hibernate use a multi-row insert versus multiple insert statements?

Comment: I would actually visit database to see what is happening under the hood. SqlServer has a profiler which can tell you almost everything. With Oracle you will rather need to visit v$sql object. [link](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=672299)

Comment: I did that and from what I could tell, it's only ever using insert statements. I did read somewhere that the hibernate logs were misleading, but I think that was because that particular example was using MySQL which has a rewriteBatchedStatements option that will do the work (I'm using Oracle).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hibernate uses multiple insert statements (one per entity to insert), but sends them to the database in batch mode (using [`Statement.addBatch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Statement.executeBatch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29)). This is the reason you're seeing multiple insert statements in the log, but also "Executing batch size: 25".

The use of batched statements greatly reduces the number of roundtrips to the database, and I would be surprised if it were less efficient than executing a single statement with multiple inserts. Moreover, it also allows mixing updates and inserts, for example, in a single database call.

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to make Hibernate use multi-row inserts, but I'm also pretty sure it would be useless.

Comment: Cool, that reassures me. I thought that's how it was working but I didn't realize that the batched statements are probably just as good as a single statement insert. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question but i had the same problem that i thought that hibernate batching means that hibernate would combine multiple inserts into one statement which it doesn't seem to do.

After some testing i found this answer that a batch of multiple inserts is just as good as a multi-row insert. I did a test inserting 1000 rows one time using hibernate batch and one time without. Both tests took about 20s so there was no performace gain in using hibernate batch.

To be sure i tried using the rewriteBatchedStatements option from the MySQL Connector/J which actually combines multiple inserts into one statement. It reduced the time to insert 1000 records down to 3s.

So after all hibernate batch seems to be useless and a real multi-row insert to be much better. Am i doing something wrong or what causes my test results?

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle bulk insert collect an array of entyty and pass in a single block to the db associating to it a unic ciclic insert/update/delete.

Is unic way to speed network throughput .

Oracle suggest to do it calling a stored procedure from hibernate passing it an array of datas.

Answer (score 0):

http://biemond.blogspot.it/2012/03/oracle-bulk-insert-or-select-from-java.html?m=1
Is not only  a software problem but infrastructural!
Problem is network data flow optimization and TCP stack fragmentation.
Mysql have function.
You have to do something like what is described in this article.
Normal transfer on network the correct volume of data is the solution

You have also to verify network mtu and Oracle sdu/tdu utilization respect data transferred between application and database